# Convert UIImage to NSData and save with core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdata

I have a `UIImageView` whose image gets set via `UIImagePicker`

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.gImage.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

I "attempt" to convert this image to `NSData` and save it with core data:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.gImage.image);
NSString *savedData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:imageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//am is a pointer to my entities class. imageData is just a NSString attribute
am.imageData = savedData;

NSError *error;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    //Handle Error
} else {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then I try to load the image in a separate file:

```
self.cell.gImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.myEntity.imageData]]];
```

I cannot see why this is not working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you had a Chance to check my answer ?

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota yes, i am going through each answer to see which one works for me, And thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can convert a UIImage to NSData like this:

**If PNG image**

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
```

**If JPG image**

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

You can store it in CoreData like so (this is one possible useful solution):

```
[newManagedObject setValue:imageData forKey:@"image"];
```

You can load the data from CoreData like this:

```
NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self yourFetchCOntroller] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[selectedObject valueForKey:@"image"]];

// Set the image to your image view  
yourimageView.image = image;
```

Comment: how does one know if its a jpg or png image? I am allowing the user to select an image from the `photoLibrary` or take it with the `camera` thank you!

Comment: mastly captured camera image is png i just put both code for converting image in to NSData my frnd.. :)

Comment: okay, thank you very much :D do you mind posting a few lines of how to get the nsdata from core data and load it into a UIImageView? Thank you very much!

Comment: hey buddy, i appreciate the help, but there is one caveat... i am not using a `NSFetchedResultsController` so what may i put instead of `[self yourFetchCOntroller]`? Thanks again!

Comment: how to convert gif image in NSData..?

Answer (score 10):

For swift its just:

`UIImage` to `NSData`

```
imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

Answer (score 3):

For storing in database:::

```
        NSInteger RandomIndex = arc4random() % 1000; 
        NSString *randomImageName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%i.png",RandomIndex]; 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:randomImageName];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:savedImagePath error:nil];
            NSLog(@"file removed from path");
        }
        NSLog(@"Saved Image Path : %@",savedImagePath);
         NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (image1 ); 
        [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];

         //am is a pointer to my entities class. imageData is just a NSString attribute
        am.imageData = randomImageName;
```

When you get that image from data base, you can write following code...

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:randomImageName];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath];
        UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:myData];
```

I think it is helpful to you.

Comment: thank you very much, i was working on this method earlier today. Unfortunately i had no success. Thank you for the reply, And on the last line of the first block of code, `am.imageData = @"imageName";` what could i replace `imageName` with? because the user is going to be selecting the image from the library/taking a picture with the camera. Thanks again!

Comment: I have just written for understanding. You can write random name and save in database. This is only for our understanding purpose. But this method is better.  NSInteger RandomIndex = arc4random() % 1000;
    NSString *imageName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%i.png",RandomIndex];

Comment: AWESOME!! :D okay, so your code works great, except when i set another image in the table view, all the images change to the newly chosen picture. And i think it has to do with the line :`NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imageName"];` What should i put in @"imageName" ? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: man this thing is pissing me off now, it doesnt even set the picture again!

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS you can let Core Data handle this for you by ticking the **Transformable** box on the attribute in the model, not selecting a specific transformer, and assigning the UIImage directly to the property.

I'm not sure if it works on iOS but it might be worth a try.

Comment: actually, it does work on iOS, the problem with this is that it was very, very slow and hard on the device for some reason. Not sure if my images are too big, thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

To convert an image to NSData try below code...

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
```

let me know it is working or not..!!!

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: Thank you for the help, however, I already have this in my code. Im just unsure why it isnt working! :(

Comment: self.cell.gImage.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];, try this one my friend, i think this code will not left your imageview blank...happy Coding!!!!!

Comment: geez, i dont know whats going on, this still isnt working! The image View is still coming up blank!

Comment: just try to NSLOG NSData, whether it is generating NSData or not..tell me

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code to save image data

to save:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

newsObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.gImage.image);

[newsObj setValue:imageData forKey:@"imgPng"];

NSError *error;

@try{

    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {

        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);


        } 
    }

}@catch (NSException *exception) {

    NSLog(@"inside exception");
}
```

To Retrive Try this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity1 = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity1];

    NSError *error;

    NSArray * array = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (array == nil) {

        NSLog(@"Testing: No results found");

    }else {

        NSLog(@"Testing: %d Results found.", [array count]);
    }

    NSData * dataBytes = [[array objectAtIndex:0] imgPng];;

    image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataBytes];

    [fetchRequest release]; 


}

@catch (NSException *exception) {

    NSLog(@"inside exception");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code save your image data into filedata and you can use it anywhere

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image1 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    {

        CGSize destinationSize = CGSizeMake(170,170);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);

       [image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width,destinationSize.height)];

       UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

       NsData *filedata  = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);

       [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done and its working for storing to nsdata.

```
[productTypeSub setValue:[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:url]] forKey:@"imgSmall"];
```

and loading to image with this code

```
ImgProductType.image= [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:productTypeSub.imgSmall];
```